# C# - Unbinding events on struct "destruction"

Tags: c#, events, memory, struct, destructor

I would like to write a script engine and use structures instead of classes to store the data of variables to avoid the memory allocation(s) involved when creating a new class instance.

My first question is : is there also a memory allocation when creating a struct, or it is created on some kind of stack (i.e either the real stack or a pre-allocated memory area where locals are stacked) ?

My second question is : imagine that a struct has some of its methods attached as event handlers onto events of other objects. How do I unbind these event handlers when the struct is destroyed since there is no destructor? Do I have to manually do it, or am I forced to use a class instead ? I wouldn't want to allocate memory for value-type data such as integers.

Comment: Structs and Classes are basically the same thing. in C# the only difference between them is that classes are pass by reference and structs are pass by values. in C++ theirs even less of a difference with the difference being that classes are private by default and structs are public by default.

Comment: @Kits That's false.  Whether a parameter is passed by value or by reference is based on whether the parameter is annotated with `ref` or `out`.  If it is, it's passed by reference, if it's not, it's passed by value.

Comment: @Kits that is **very very wrong**; please don't perpetuate that - it is ... a complete misunderstanding

Comment: my bad, its been a while since i done c#. i may be confusing languages

Comment: I'd just use classes and write *simple* understandable code first. Then *profile* and consider whether you *need* to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: This question seems to talk about a scripting runtime that has a memory manager that is broken by design.  How that is supposed to come to a good end anyway is but a guess.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure how you would be able to judge whether a design is broken when it hasn't been presented to you.
In other words, the idea is to reserve memory allocations for reference type values, such as strings, arrays, closures, etc and avoid them for integers, reals, booleans or null values. This is why I am wondering if I could use a struct instead of a class to avoid the cost of a memory allocation when dealing with non reference-types. I know it's always better to wait before thinking about optimisation, but some optimisations are obvious.

Comment: This question is absolutely not too broad, as evidenced by it receiving two very specific answers. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use value types for their supposed efficiency. If something is not meant to be a value type by design, don't make it a value type to gain a few CPU cycles.

> I would like to [...] use structures instead of classes [to] avoid the memory allocation(s) involved when creating a new class instance.

I think you mean "dynamic memory allocation", because there's definitely some memory allocated to each `struct`.

Depending on the situation, there may be dynamic memory allocation in conjunction with using a `struct`. Specifically, this would happen when you box your `struct` as an `object`.

> is there also a memory allocation when creating a `struct`, or it is created on some kind of stack?

The memory for value types is allocated on the stack if this is a local variable, or inside the class that hosts the value, if it is a field inside another `struct` or a `class`.

> some of its methods attached as event handlers onto events of other objects. How do I unbind event handlers when the struct is destroyed since there is no destructor?

Let's not get ahead of ourselves, and first consider how to attach methods of a `struct` as handlers to events of other objects. When you do the attachment, your `struct` would be boxed for capturing into an event handler's closure, which has a potential of creating a great deal of confusion.

Consider this example:

```
delegate void Foo();

struct Bar {
    public int X;
    public void DoIt() {
        X++;
        Console.WriteLine("X={0}", X);
    }
}
public static void Main() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    var foo = new Foo(b.DoIt); // Watch out!
    foo();
    foo();
    foo();
    Console.WriteLine("X={0} What???", b.X);
}
```

When you call `foo` event handler, `X` inside `Bar` gets modified as expected. But look what happens when you check the actual value of `X` inside `b`, from which you created a delegate: its value remains zero! ([demo 1](https://ideone.com/aSfcrb))

This behavior changes once you make `Bar` a class ([demo 2](https://ideone.com/lxXFH8)).

The moral of this story is that you should be very careful with value types, especially in contexts where capturing is required, such as making delegates. If you make a delegate on a local variable, you know where the scope of that variable ends, so you can properly dispose of that delegate:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
try {
    someClass.SomeEvent += b.DoIt();
} finally {
    someClass.SomeEvent -= b.DoIt();    
}
```

However, if a delegate extends the scope of the variable beyond local, the behavior is going to be unexpected and confusing.

Comment: Note: that's showing *boxing*, not *closures*; the `new Foo(b.DoIt)` is (IIRC) a `ldarg`, `box`, `ldftn`, `newobj`; as with all boxing, the state of the struct will be snapshotted at the `box`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right, there's unintentional boxing going on here. I edited the example to make it easier to understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of a finalizer, but a `struct` can still implement `IDisposable`. Frankly, though, I would argue that it is incorrect and confusing to do so, simply because the life cycle is so different. For example:

```
var x = new SomeStruct(); // fine
var y = x; // hmm....
```

Now we have two *copies* of the struct. If you're "done" with `x`, does that mean you're "done" with `y`? There's also huge problems with identity and boxing - since events track a target *object*. Frankly, it is hugely problematic to do anything complex involving structs as event subscribers, unless everything goes out of scope at the same time. To give an example: this writes `Hi` **twice** because the unsubscribe is a different **box** - so essentially the unsubscribe fails:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new Foo();
        TheThing += x.Bar;
        TheThing?.Invoke();
        TheThing -= x.Bar;
        TheThing?.Invoke();
    }
    static event Action TheThing;
}
struct Foo
{
    public void Bar() => Console.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

Comment: as a side note, it should be mentioned that each *box* is itself another copy of the struct, which a: makes it even more difficult to talk about the life cycle of a struct, and b: makes it even more relevant to treat structs as immutable - any mutations after the subscribe will be isolated from the box

Comment: Thanks for your help. What could you tell me about my first question ?

Comment: @Virus721 you mean where is it allocated? structs are simply: in the thing that owns them. If you're talking about a *local variable* (except for iterator blocks, captured variables, etc), then since local variables live on the stack, it is on the stack; if you're talking about a *field*, then: it is wherever that thing "with the field" is. If the parent is a class, or the parent is a struct that is *in turn* on a class, then it is on the managed heap. If it is an element in an array, then it is on the managed heap. But in those cases, the only *allocation* is when the *parent* is allocated

Comment: Ok so it's exactly like a C++ automatic variable.

Comment: @Virus721 I can't comment on that with confidence, but my gut says "probably: not really, no"